# Alternate for window.opener

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am trying to access javascript variable in the parent window from the child window like this.

```
window.opener.jsvar = 'something';
```

This is not working sometimes in IE 6.x But it is fine in firefox/IE 7.X

Do we have any alternative for window.opener?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know we haven't alternative for window.opener. Need to catch this bug and fix.